# Cloudfront giving temporary access denied

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have this scenario:

1. User initiates a process
2. Server constructs and uploads a file to S3
3. User attempts to access file through Cloudfront

   #2 and #3 are asynchronous, so it's possible that the user can attempt to access the file before it is uploaded to S3.

   When I try to access the file on cloudfront, I get an Access Denied error. 
   However, I can verify that the file exists on S3, and is accessible.

If I wait a minute or two, this access denied error is gone, and I can access my file through cloudfront. What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventual Consistency seems to be my problem.

All cloudfront distributions have it.
The S3 Virginia region also has it.